# match date from list of strings returns empty list

Tags: python, regex, list, date

I believe my question is very simple, but I couldn't put my finger on why it doesn't work.
I have list of items, which is similar to this:

```
['location_1/2021-05-12.tiff','location_1/2021-05-17.tiff','location_1/2021-05-19.tiff',
'location_1/2021-05-24.tiff','location_1/2021-05-28.tiff','location_1/2021-05-30.tiff'...]
```

I want to get new list that will contain only the dates, something like this:

```
['2021-05-12','2021-05-17','2021-05-19','021-05-24','2021-05-28','021-05-30']
```

I have tried to do that with regex:

```
dates_Values = list(filter(lambda x: match('([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})', x), my_list))
```

however, it returns empty list.

How can I get correct list with only dates?

Comment: `[s.split("/")[1].split(".")[0] for s in your_list]` ?

Comment: You need `search()` not `match()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex never matches as no string starts with a date:

> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
> If zero or more characters **at the beginning of string** match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)

---

You can split it out like so:

```
l = ['location_1/2021-05-12.tiff','location_1/2021-05-17.tiff',
     'location_1/2021-05-19.tiff','location_1/2021-05-24.tiff',
     'location_1/2021-05-28.tiff','location_1/2021-05-30.tiff']

print([s.split("/")[1].split(".")[0] for s in l])
```

Output:

```
['2021-05-12', '2021-05-17', '2021-05-19', '2021-05-24', '2021-05-28', '2021-05-30']
```

---

Or keep the regex approach:

```
import re

l = ['location_1/2021-05-12.tiff','location_1/2021-05-17.tiff',
     'location_1/2021-05-19.tiff','location_1/2021-05-24.tiff',
     'location_1/2021-05-28.tiff','location_1/2021-05-30.tiff']


found = re.findall(r"/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).", str.join(" ", l))
print(found)
```

Output:

```
['2021-05-12', '2021-05-17', '2021-05-19', '2021-05-24', '2021-05-28', '2021-05-30']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use **non-regex** solution combining `str.rsplit` with `maxsplit` parameter for the above data in a list-comprehension:

```py
>>> [i.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0].rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[-1] for i in my_list]
['2021-05-12', '2021-05-17', '2021-05-19', '2021-05-24', '2021-05-28', '2021-05-30']
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Hii, Check this out its working fine 

let arr = [
    "location_1/2021-05-12.tiff",
    "location_1/2021-05-17.tiff",
    "location_1/2021-05-19.tiff",
    "location_1/2021-05-24.tiff",
    "location_1/2021-05-28.tiff",
    "location_1/2021-05-30.tiff",
  ];
  
const newArr = arr.map((item,i) => {
  return  item.match("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}");
  });
  

  let dates_Values = []
  dates_Values = newArr.map((item,i,arr)=> {
     return item[0]
  })

  console.log(dates_Values);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re 
strs = ['location_1/2021-05-12.tiff','location_1/2021-05-17.tiff','location_1/2021-05-19.tiff','location_1/2021-05-24.tiff','location_1/2021-05-28.tiff','location_1/2021-05-30.tiff']

dates_Values = [ re.search(r'([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})', x).group(1) for x in strs]
```

Output

```
['2021-05-12', '2021-05-17', '2021-05-19', '2021-05-24', '2021-05-28', '2021-05-30']
```

Comment: @Reut if you filter then you need an extra step

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
t = ['location_1/2021-05-12.tiff','location_1/2021-05-17.tiff','location_1/2021-05-19.tiff','location_1/2021-05-24.tiff','location_1/2021-05-28.tiff','location_1/2021-05-30.tiff']
dates_values = []
search_pattern = re.compile('([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})')
for s in t:
    matchResult = search_pattern.search(s)
    if matchResult:
        print(matchResult.group(1))
        dates_values.append(matchResult.group(1))
print(dates_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over each element and search for date format by using
**r'\d+-\d+-\d+'** pattern and append that elements to new list.

```
import re

my_list = ['location_1/2021-05-12.tiff','location_1/2021-05-17.tiff','location_1/2021-05-19.tiff', 'location_1/2021-05-24.tiff','location_1/2021-05-28.tiff']

new_list = []

for element in my_list:
    result = re.findall(r'\d+\-\d+\-\d+', element)
    if result:
        new_list.append(result[0])

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Here variable result is will be in the list format so while appending you have to use either indexing 0 or -1 of the result.